# python dataframe how to convert set column to list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, set

I tried to convert a set column to list in python dataframe, but failed. Not sure what's best way to do so. Thanks.

Here is the example:
I tried to create a 'c' column which convert 'b' set column to list. but 'c' is still set.

```
data = [{'a': [1,2,3], 'b':{11,22,33}},{'a':[2,3,4],'b':{111,222}}]
tdf = pd.DataFrame(data)
tdf['c'] = list(tdf['b'])
tdf
           a             b             c
0  [1, 2, 3]  {33, 11, 22}  {33, 11, 22}
1  [2, 3, 4]    {222, 111}    {222, 111}
```

Comment: This should never be a dataframe in the first place. You have non-scalar values in columns, you're making life harder for yourself. You will get no benefit of pandas at all through this structure.

Comment: Related meta: [Generic “Don't Do It” Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373714/generic-dont-do-it-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'a': [1,2,3], 'b':{11,22,33}},{'a':[2,3,4],'b':{111,222}}]
tdf = pd.DataFrame(data)

tdf['c'] = [list(e) for e in tdf.b]

print(tdf)
```

Comment: @U9-Forward if you see `map`, `apply`, `lambda`, `np.vectorize` (a complete misnomer)... it's running in Python time.

Answer (score 3):

Use `apply`:

```
tdf['c'] = tdf['b'].apply(list)
```

Because using `list` is doing to whole column not one by one.

Or do:

```
tdf['c'] = tdf['b'].map(list)
```